# HDFS "files" that are directories

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, hdfs, parquet

Background--we are trying to read different file types (csv or parquet) into pyspark, and I have the task of writing a program that will determine file type.

It appears that parquet files are always directories, parquet file appears in HDFS as a directory.

We have some csv files that are also directories, where the file name is the directory name and the directory contains several part files.  What processes do this?

Why are some files --'files' and some files 'directories'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend on what process produced those files. For example, when MapReduce produces output, it always produces a directory and then creates one output file per reducer within that directory. This is done so that each reducer can create its output independently.

Judging from Spark's [CSV package](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv), it expects to output to a single file. So perhaps the single-file CSVs are being generated by Spark and the directories by MapReduce.

To be as generic as possible, it may be a good idea to do the following: check if the file in question is a directory. If not, check the extension. If yes, look at the extension of the files inside of the directory. This should work for each of your situations.

Note that some input formats (e.g. MapReduce input formats) will *only* accept directories as inputs, and some (e.g. Spark's `textFile`) will only accept files/globs of files. You need to be aware of what is expected from the libraries you are interacting with.

Comment: Thanks!  That is what I was missing that Mapreduce spits out files as a directory.   I've been on the governing things so long that I never looked at what MR actual does for output.    Since our program is designed to be very general, I will need to include a case for that, but now I know where this different 'types' are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

> All the data on your hard drive consists of files and folders. The
>   basic difference between the two is that files store data, while
>   folders store files and other folders.

Hadoop execution engines generally creates a directory and write multiple part files as output based on the number of reducers or executors used.

When you many an output file *abc.csv* it doesn't mean that its a single file with the data. Its just the output location which MapReduce (generally) interprets as the new directory to be created within which it creates the output files(part files).
In case of Spark when you are writing a file(maybe using `.saveAsTextFile`) it may creates only a single file.